# How to write XML to a URL?

Tags: android, xml, apache2

I am trying to write an XML file to a URL, e.g. http://myIPAddress/myFolder/myFile.xml .
I am using an Apache2 server for my tests on Ubuntu 10.10.

Output line example (ignore apostrophe):

```
<'myEntity id="1" name="me" />
```

Also, I want to able to reopen the connection anytime and add lines to the end of the file.

I'd post my attempt here for correction but it's a sad one.
I am trying `OutputStreamWriter` with `URLConnection`, please correct me if I should be using a different approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using HttpClient (built into Android) with either `HttpPost` or `HttpPut`, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi brotha, thx for the quick reply. I'll look it up when I am at work tomorrow and see how it goes.

Comment: hi brotha, i got it and i am using HttpPost but nothing shows up on my server and no execution is thrown! here's my code:myClient= new DefaultHttpClient();
   
   StringEntity myString = new StringEntity("important message");
   
   HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.218.211/pasturecovers.xml");
   httpPost.setEntity(myString);
   myClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: the response returnes "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" but the file's contents in the server do not change, it's just blank!

Comment: @ZiGi: What makes you think that this POST request is supposed to change the file's contents?

Comment: shux! i read it from apache's HttpClient 4 docs. what to use then!?

Comment: i just need to figure out how to use php! works like a charm bro thanks heaps!!